# react not rerendering after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know there have been similar questions, but I have a weird issue.

This is what I'm doing

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Table, Button, InputGroup, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';

function App() {
  const [pons, setPons] = useState();
  const [translations, setTranslations] = useState([]);
  const [isInEditMode, setIsInEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('samochod');
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
  const [translationsToSave, setTranslationsToSave] = useState([]);

  const changeIsInEditMode = () => setIsInEditMode(!isInEditMode);
  const handleEditButtonClick = (id) => console.log('Edit', id);
  const handleDeleteButtonClick = (id) => console.log('Delete', id);
  const handleInputChange = (e) => setInputValue(e.target.value);
  const handleFetchOnButtonClick = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/pons/findTranslation/${inputValue}`).then(r => r.json()).catch(e => console.log(e));
    if (resp.ok === true) {
      setTranslations(resp.resp[0].hits);
      setErrors([]);
    } else {
      setErrors(resp.errors ? resp.errors : ['Something went wrong. check the input']);
    }
  };
  const handleSaveTranslations = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch('localhost:8080/pons/', {method: 'POST', body: {content: translationsToSave}});
    if (resp.ok === true) {
      setInputValue('');
      setTranslations(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {errors.length > 0 ? errors.map(e => <div key={e}>{e}</div>) : null}
      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <FormControl
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          placeholder={inputValue}
        />
      </InputGroup>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <Button onClick={handleFetchOnButtonClick} disabled={inputValue === '' || errors.length > 0}>Translate</Button>
        <Button onClick={changeIsInEditMode}>
          {isInEditMode ? 'Exit edit mode' : 'Enter edit mode'}
        </Button>

        <Button disabled={translationsToSave.length === 0} onClick={handleSaveTranslations}>Save translations</Button>
      </div>
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Original</th>
          <th>Translation</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {translations ? translations.map(pon => pon.roms.map(rom => rom.arabs.map(arab => arab.translations.map(translation => {
          const {source, target} = translation;
          return (
            <tr>
              <td><span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: source}}/></td>
              <td><span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: target}}/></td>
              <td>
                {
                  !translationsToSave.includes(target) ?
                    <Button onClick={() => {
                      const tmp = translationsToSave;
                      tmp.push(target);
                      setTranslationsToSave(tmp);
                    }}>
                      Add translation
                    </Button>
                    :
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => {
                        const tmp = translationsToSave;
                        tmp.splice(tmp.findIndex(elem => elem === target));
                        setTranslationsToSave(tmp);
                      }}>
                      Remove translation
                    </Button>
                }
              </td>
            </tr>
          )
        })))) : (
          <div>No translations</div>
        )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So it's a basic app, it right now just adds and removes from an array wit `setTranslationsToSave`. After I click the `Add translation` button the view stays the same. But it refreshes when I click `Enter edit mode`. Same with `Remove translation`. I need to click `Enter/Exit edit mode`.

Hitting `Translate` also reloads the view. So the `Add/Remove translation` buttons are the only ones which do not refresh the page. Why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are mutating the satte in Add/Remove translation button, so when react check before re-rendering if the state updater was called with the same state it feels that nothing has changed as it does a reference check and ehnce doesn't trigger re-render

Also while updating current state based on previous state use `functional callback approach for state updater`.

Update your state like below

```
  <Button onClick={() => {
                  setTranslationsToSave(prev => [...prev, target]);
                }}>
                  Add translation
                </Button>
                :
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {

                    setTranslationsToSave((prev) => {
                         const index = prev.findIndex(elem => elem === target));                    return [...prev.slice(0, index), ...prev.slice(index + 1)]
                    });
                  }}>
                  Remove translation
                </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Add translation` click handler, you're mutating the state:

```
<Button onClick={() => {
    // tmp is just a reference to state
    const tmp = translationsToSave;
    // You are mutating state, this will be lost
    tmp.push(target);
    setTranslationsToSave(tmp);
}}>
```

You should duplicate the state and add the new element:

```
<Button onClick={() => {
    setTranslationsToSave([...translationsToSave, target]);
}}>
```